# Как создать выпадающее меню, в котором будут все участники Discord-сервера

Tags: python, discord.py, discord, disnake

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на меню под сообщением в его параметрах выводились все участники сервера с возможностью их поиска. Вот код выпадающего меню:

```
        options = []

    select = disnake.ui.StringSelect(
        custom_id='helpmenu',
        placeholder='Выберите ивент',
        options=options
    )
```

Что можно сделать? Видел, что эта реализация возможна, но сам повторить не могу

Comment: Допустим, класс элемента списка называется `SelectOption`. Тогда будет так: `options = [SelectOption(label=member.name) for member in guild.members]`

Comment: @denisnumb не то. а если учитывать, что на сервере больше 25 людей? код выдаёт ошибку - SelectMenu больше 25 параметров не принимает

Comment: Если больше 25 элементов нельзя, то это ограничение никак и не обойти. Нужно придумывать другой способ выбора участников

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `disnake.ui.UserSelect`

Ссылка на доки:
https://docs.disnake.dev/en/stable/api/ui.html#disnake.ui.UserSelect

Пример кода:

```
class selectUser(discord.ui.UserSelect):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(
      placeholder="Выберите пользователя...",
      min_values=1,
      max_values=1,
      custom_id = 'select_user_dropdown'
    )

@client.listen("on_dropdown")
async def dropdownListen(inter):
  if inter.component.custom_id == "select_user_dropdown":
    print(inter.values[0]) # айди выбранного пользователя
    # действия после выбора
```